# Редирект .htaccess 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Как сделать редирект для такого вида адреса

```
http://site.ru/site/viza?continent=1&country=81
```

на

```
http://site.ru/site/viza/
```

**Обновление**

Есть сайт `http://www.site.kz/`. Я затер файлик по фтп `.htaccess`, он был скрытый. Ссылки на разделы типа `http://www.site.kz/site/viza` теперь не работают. Пробую так

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/site/viza|/about/index|/site/med)
```

Не получается. Как правильно сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^continent=1&country=81$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/viza$
RewriteRule .* /site/viza/? [R=301, L]
```

**Обновление**

Если в `.htaccess` у вас были правила для построения адресов таких страниц (роутинг), а вы затерли файлом, содержащим только мои строчки, то никак. Надо восстанавливать старый `.htaccess` и добавлять туда эти строчки.